# How to avoid axis line disappearing when using ggarrange?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'd like to arrange two facet plots using `ggarrange` (in order to get x axes aligned).

```
library(egg)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(warpbreaks) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = wool)) +
  facet_wrap(~tension, ncol = 2, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = .1),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank())

p2 <- ggplot(warpbreaks) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = tension)) +
  facet_wrap(~wool) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = "black", size = .1),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        strip.background = element_blank())

ggarrange(p1, p2, ncol = 2)
```

[image]

Works great, but unfortunately the vertical axis lines disappeared. This does not happen when using `grid.arrange`, but at least for my real data there the x axes are not aligned, hence my wish to use `ggarrange`. Is there a way to keep the axis lines?

Comment: it seems to be related to the clipping issue of the y-axis line; it doesn't disappear entirely but half of it is clipped by the plot panel. Try adding `panel.background = element_blank()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr: setting `panel.background = element_blank()` should restore the axes.**

I think it's a combination of a clipping issue in ggplot2 (the y axis line can be clipped by the plot panel, cutting its width in half), and egg::gtable_frame placing the axis below the plot panel.

```
library(egg)
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot(warpbreaks) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = wool)) +
  facet_wrap(~tension, ncol = 2, scales = "free_x") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.line = element_line(colour = alpha("red", 0.5), size = 5),
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = alpha("white", 0.5), 
                                        linetype = 2, colour = "black"),
        strip.background = element_blank())

p1
```

[image]

```
g1 <- ggplotGrob(p1)
gg <- gtable_frame(g1)
grid.newpage()
grid.draw(gg)
```

[image]

Comment: This goes in `theme()` in your original `ggplot()` in case it's not immediately obvious to anybody else.